# Why can't I see the Nuka-World map?

Tags: fallout-4

When I'm in Nuka World, I can't actually see the map. It's just maybe one or more icons crammed into one corner of the normal Commonwealth map.

That's what it looks like:

[image: BrokenMap]

I do have mods but none of them add new areas, mess with the current ones, and I've never had this problem before.

Comment: Though they may not made to intentionally mess with the game world, they still could be. Just try disabling the mods first and seeing if the maps corrects itself. If not, the problem is something else.

Comment: Thanks, Mattbat, it was a mod and I pinned down exactly which one was causing the problem.

Comment: You are welcome, 404592. P.S. I would reccomend changing your name :)

Comment: Also may be a good idea to report the bug to the mod makers, if that's even possible. They may not be able to fix it, but there's always a chance they could.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue and the mod that ended up being the problem for me was the "Build High - Settlements Expanded" mod.

Answer (score 3):

Answer was in comments.

As [The Mattbatt999](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/188005/the-mattbat999) suggested, it was a mod that was causing this issue. Disabling the mods on the game resolved the problem.

> Though they may not made to intentionally mess with the game world, they still could be. Just try disabling the mods first and seeing if the maps corrects itself. If not, the problem is something else. – The Mattbat999 Oct 15 '18 at 19:47
>
> Thanks, Mattbat, it was a mod and I pinned down exactly which one was causing the problem. – Arlynna Oct 16 '18 at 6:11

Comment: Perhaps it would be nice to say which mod it was, for future visitors? Don't want something like [this relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/979/) after all.

Comment: @Arlynna has only made this post over the course of the year they've been on Arqade. I don't think we'll get an answer as to which mod it is.